# x position of tooltip in d3 stacked bar chart not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I don't really know why but my xPosition in the stacked bar chart that I am working on is not really working. Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

No matter what bar I hover over it always comes out on the side:

[image]

Here's a JS Bin code that I am working on: https://jsbin.com/qudoyewiba/edit?js,output

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the console, the console is your friend. You have a lot of NaNs. The reason is simple: your `rect` elements don't have a "x" attribute. So, this doesn't work:

```
var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x"));
```

Instead, you have to get the "x" translation of the group that is the parent of that respective rectangle:

```
var group = d3.select(d3.select(this).node().parentNode);
var xPos = d3.transform(group.attr("transform")).translate[0];
```

Here is your working code: https://jsbin.com/dutetokoti/1/edit

Comment: No worries. Have in mind that `d3.transform` was removed in D3 version 4... so, this snippet will not work if you update your code to v4.

Comment: I am currently working with version 3, but I will keep that in mind. Thanks for the tip.